# Как удалить вторую запятую в тексте?

Tags: c, строки

В тексте две и более запятых. Нужно удалить вторую запятую. Как это сделать?

Написала так, сказали, что нельзя использовать замену на пробел (' ')

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    char str[255];
    int i,k=0;
    printf("Vvedite stroku:");
    gets(str);
    for(i=0; i<=255; i++)
    {
        if(str[i]==',')
            k++;
        if(k==2)
        {
            str[i]=' ';
            i=256;
        }
    }
    printf("%s",str);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *сказали, что нельзя использовать замену на пробел* Правильно сказали. Удаление сделает строку на 1 символ короче. А замена на пробел оставит её длину как есть.

Comment: можете показать на примере, как удалить символ из строки? а то не очень понимаю :(

Comment: Идите от конца строки в цикле и если встречаете две запятых перемещаете конец строки на одну позиции влево.

Comment: Вы знаете, как получить часть строки от символа номер X до символа номер Y? В момент, когда найдена вторая запятая, номера начальных/конечных символов подстроки до неё и подстроки после неё легко вычисляются... И, надеюсь, как конкатенировать две строки, Вы тоже знаете. А если можно использовать какую-нить библиотеку регулярок, так оно и вовсе элементарно...

Comment: Заведите второй буфер на 256 символов и в цикле копируйте все символы (кроме символов запятой) из входной строки в этот буфер. По окончании процесса во втором буфере у Вас будет исходная строка с удаленными запятыми. Признак окончания процесса как всегда нулевой символ в строке.

Comment: Мой ответ - убегал, спешил, промахнулся... это ответ не на ваш вопрос. Извините!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот без сложных буферов и прочего:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char str[256];
    int comma_counter = 0;
    char c;

    for(int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
        c = getchar();

        if(c == ',') {
            comma_counter++;
            if(comma_counter == 2) {
                i--;
                continue;
            }
        }

        if(c == '\n') {
            str[i] = '\0';
            break;
        }

        str[i] = c;
    }

    printf("%s\n", str);
    printf("%d commas", comma_counter);

    return 0;
}
```

Ввод:

```
qwe, qwe, qwe, qwe,,,,, qew, qew,
```

Собственно, вывод:

```
qwe, qwe qwe, qwe,,,,, qew, qew,
10 commas
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот что получилось:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_LEN_STR 255

int main()
{
    char str[MAX_LEN_STR];
    char str1[MAX_LEN_STR];
    int i,k;
    printf("Vvedite stroku:");
    gets(str);
    for(i=0,k=0; ;++i)
    {
        if(str[i]==0) {++k;break;}
        if(str[i]==',') continue;
        str1[k]=str[i];
        ++k;
    }
    str1[k]=0;
    printf("%s",str1);
    return 0;
}
```

Этот код удаляет все запятые в исходной строке. Результирующая строка str1 будет короче, чем исходная, если в исходной строке были запятые.

Проверялось на

https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c++_compiler

Вот вариант, который удаляет только вторую запятую в тексте:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_LEN_STR 255

int main()
{
    char str[MAX_LEN_STR];
    char str1[MAX_LEN_STR];
    int i,j,k;
    printf("Vvedite stroku:");
    gets(str);
    for(i=0,k=0,j=0; ;++i)
    {
        if(str[i]==0) break;

        if(str[i]==',') {
            ++j;
            if(j==2) continue;
        }
        str1[k]=str[i];
        ++k;
    }
    str1[k]=0;
    printf("%s",str1);
    return 0;
}
```

Проверялось там же.